# Is SSH public key need to be the same each time I do push/pull with git repository?

Tags: git, ssh, github, ssh-keys

I am just started using Git, so I apologize if it is a newbie question.
I am using two different machines to commit changes to remote Git repository on github.com. Do I need to use the same SSH public key (the one I mentioned for my repository on Github)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No -- if you go to your GitHub accounts page, you can add as many SSH public keys as you want.